# Equation numbering starts with equation 2 instead of 1

Tags: equations, numbering

Can someone give me a hint, why my latex file starts to number the  equations with equation 2 instead of equation 1?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm}
\allowdisplaybreaks  % para que pueda partir fórmulas que ocupan más de una línea, 
necesita el paquete anterior
\usepackage{amssymb} % para cargar algunos símbolos como \blacksquare y \square
\setcounter{equation}{1}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % para cargar algunas fuentes en estilo matemático
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{blkarray}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}



% Crossing text in equation
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

% no indent
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

% Set size of figure font
% The different size options are: scriptsize, footnotesize, small, normalsize, large, 
Large
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}

% Área de impresión de una página:
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%  \geometry{hmargin={2.5cm,2.5cm}, height=22cm}
\geometry{top = 2.5cm, left = 2cm, right = 2cm, bottom=2cm}

% Set borders
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{top = 2cm, left = 2cm, right = 2cm, bottom=2cm}  % 
{a4paper,left=40mm,right=30mm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm}

% Hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref} %\href

% Drawing a graph in Latex
\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\definecolor {processblue}{cmyk}{0.96,0,0,0}
\newcommand{\Cross}{$\mathbin{\tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.2ex, red] \draw (0,0) - 
- (1,1) (0,1) -- (1,0);}$}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all}

% Package to draw a pie chart
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

% Space in tabular above and below every line, needs to at it at the end of the line. 
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut


\theoremstyle{definition}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{skipbelow = 10pt}

% itemize indent (set margin)
%\usepackage{lipsum, enumitem}

% set line spacing
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

% Für multicolums in itemize
\usepackage{multicol}   

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%Set equation counter to 0.
\newcommand{\startparent}{%
\setcounter{equation}{0}%
\xdef\theparentequation{\arabic{parentequation}}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{Lineare Funktionen}
\subsection{Einführung}
In Alltagssituationen begegnen uns ständig Anwendungen von linearen Funktionen. Nehmen 
wir an, wir möchten eine lineare Funktion aufstellen, die uns die jährlichen Stromkosten 
(in CHF) in Abhängigkeit von unserem Stromverbrauch (in kWh) liefert. \\
Die Eniwa (Stromversorger in Aarau) verrechnet eine Grundgebühr von 9.50 CHF pro Monat 
für einen Stromanschluss und 0.098 CHF/kWh Stromverbrauch.\\


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
set thousands separator={},
xmin=0,xmax=5000,
ymin=0,ymax=600,
grid=both,
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=darkgray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=darkgray!50},
axis lines=middle,
samples=1,
xlabel={Stromverbrauch [kWh]},
ylabel={Jahresstromkosten [CHF]}]
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Zwischen der Definitionsmenge $\mathbb{D}$, dem Stromverbrauch v in kWh, und der 
Wertemenge $\mathbb{W}$, den monatlichen Stromkosten k in [kWh], besteht ein linearer 
Zusammenhang, der durch die folgende Funktionsgleichung ausgedrückt werden kann:
\begin{equation}
k(v) = \frac{49}{500}v+114
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

As you can see tried the %Set equation counter to 0, but it didn't made a difference.

Comment: Unrelated: remember, with very few exceptions, `hyperref` should be the last package loaded (as it has to mess with other packages you might have loaded)

Comment: please post more reasonable example without all the unrelated code, but you are forcing thenumbering to start from 2 as you have `\setcounter{equation}{1}`

Comment: Secondly, you really should not remove the paragraph indentation

Comment: Thirdly, does this example even compile without errors? You have a stray line with geometry option right above where you load hyperref

Comment: @daleif it would compile except the OP has allowwd two or three commented lines to linewrap while copying them here, so it's markdown errors essentially.

Answer (score 5):

If I remove all the unrelated lines, a more reasonable version of your example would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{equation}{1}
\end{document}
\begin{equation}
k(v) = \frac{49}{500}v+114
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which is forcing the numbering to start at 2. If you delete `\setcounter{equation}{1}`  then you will get the default numbering.